# Google Analytics not installed on my Rails App on Heroku (with domain masking)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, heroku, google-analytics

My Rails app is hosted on nameless-brushlands-1926.herokuapp.com and on the www.eutaste.com  domain.

I set up Google Analytics yesterday on the eutaste.com domain by putting the tracking code in a footer partial in Views layouts of the app.

I have tried configuring the Date range to today, but there isn't any traffic on the report.

Under the `Admin` tab -> `Tracking Code`, I see the status as being

> Tracking Not Installed

Following the advice from similar issues, I have looked at the "Network" tab on my browser, which shows an `analytics.js`.  Is this an indication of it working and a sign that I should just wait?

Perhaps taking a step back, am I even setting it up properly?

Answer (score 1):

I can see the request there going to Google when I load the page, sometimes it just takes Google Analytics a while to catch up

Comment: but is it correct to have analytics set up on the eutaste.com domain, when it is just masking and redirecting to a heroku app?

Comment: ah, now I see - eutaste.com is using some kind of iframe onto the herokuapp.com url. It's not a problem for Google Analytics but I would look into setting it up with the iframe and setting the www.eutaste.com to be a CNAME to <appname>.herokuapp.com instead.